# What is the way to print value of a 2D int array on textView field - android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays

What is the code to print/display the value of a two dimensional array (int) on TextView field in android studio?
I want the result to come out on TextView when user puts row, column value on EditText fields and clicks the button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText value01, value02;
Button show;
TextView result;

int mpaTable[][] = new int[4][4];
int[][] MpaTable = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16}
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    value01 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value01);
    value02 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value02);
    show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result); }
public void btnClick(View V){

    int a = Integer.parseInt(value01.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(value02.getText().toString());

    result.setText(mpaTable[a][b]);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried with the above code but the result comes error.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Make sure that you set the text field as a string. Right now the MpaTable returns an int, so you'll need to add String.valueOf(mpaTable[a][b]);

Comment: I changed to result.setText(String.valueOf(mpaTable[a][b])); but result shows 0 after putting data.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

result.setText(a+"---"+b);

It will work for you.

Comment: Solved.. Actually the problem was with the array. I fixed it.